# Why does "3.5".matches("[0-9]+") return false?

Tags: java, regex

I use the method `String.matches(String regex)` to find if a string matches the regex expression

From my point of view the regular expression `regex="[0-9]+"` means a String that contains at least one figure between 0 and 9

But when I debug `"3.5".matches("[0-9]+")` it returns false.

So what is wrong ?

Answer (score 8):

`matches` determines if the regex matches the *whole* string.  It won't return `true` if the string *contains* a match.

To test if the string contains a match to a given regex, use `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(string).find()`.

(Your regex, `[0-9]+`, will match any string that contains only digits from 0 to 9, and at least one digit.  It doesn't magically match against any real number.  If you want something matching any real number, look at e.g. the [Javadoc for `Double.valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29), which specifies a regex used in validating doubles.  That regex allows hexadecimal input, NaNs, and infinities, but it should give you a better idea of what's required.)

Alternately, edit the regex so it directly matches any string containing one or more digits, e.g. `.*[0-9]+.*` would do the job.

Comment: `.*[0-9]+.*` does match any string with a # in it, but I don't think that is what the OP is looking for.  Sounds like he was confused thinking that his regex would match numerically instead of as a string. `.*[0-9]+.*` matches `3.5` sure, but it also matches `a1b`. You have the best explanation but maybe incorporate the regex from RoddyoftheFrozenPea's answer? +1 with update

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match decimal numbers, your reg ex needs to be `\d*\.?\d+`. If you want negatives as well, then `\-?\d*\.?\d+`.

Answer (score 1):

`.` is not `0-9` and `matches` tests the entire string.